# Scrapy is not able to scrape the email field from website

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape a website for its data and it seems like the javascript on the browser is stopping to get the email address.

Would someone please let me know how to get an email address?

website: https://directory.easternuc.com/publicDirectory

```py
from scrapy import cmdline
import scrapy
from tutorial.items import TutorialItem


class DemoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "DemoSpider"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = []
        for page in range(1, 3):
            url = "https://directory.easternuc.com/publicDirectory?page=%s" %page
            urls.append(url)

        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):

        item = TutorialItem()
        index = 1
        for _ in response.selector.xpath("//tr/td/h4/text()").getall():
            item['name'] = response.selector.xpath("//tr[%s]/td/h4/text()" % index).get()
            item['phone'] = response.selector.xpath("//tr[%s]/td[2]/text()" % index).get()
            item['mobile'] = response.selector.xpath("//tr[%s]/td[3]/text()" % index).get()
            item['email'] = response.selector.xpath("//tr[%s]/td[4]/text()" % index).get()
            index += 1
            yield item
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because those email are not immediate child of `td` tag

Please try this code

```
def parse(self, response):
    for tr in response.xpath("//table/tr"):
        item = TutorialItem()
        item['name'] = tr.xpath("./td[1]/h4/text()").get()
        item['phone'] = tr.xpath("./td[2]/text()").get()
        item['mobile'] = tr.xpath("./td[3]/text()").get()
        item['email'] = "".join(tr.xpath("./td[4]//text()").getall())
        yield item
```